# How get local IANA zone name in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, timezone

In python 3 how to get local zone name (e.g Australia/Sydney)

I tried like this

```
import datetime

local_tzname = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo
print(local_tzname)
```

this outputs like this

> AEDT

But I want to output like this which is the local time zone name

> Australia/Sydney

I can execute *timedatectl* in a subprocess and read the output but that is not what I want.
The script I am writing need to be executed on several RedHat (7/8/9) Ubuntu servers where I don't have control of available modules. Therefore it must use available modules when python 3 get installed.

Therefore my requirement is

1. use native python 3 available modules
2. not to use external commands and read the output (e.g. use subprocess )
3. Not require any special module to be installed e.g. tzlocal

zoneinfo is a good module to work with IANA format but I couldn't use that to get the system time zone

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understood your request correctly:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

zone = ZoneInfo('Australia/Sydney')
dt = datetime.now(tz=zone)
print(dt.strftime(fmt))
print(dt.tzname())
print(dt.tzinfo)
```

Output:

```
2024-01-31 21:37:41 AEDT+1100
AEDT
Australia/Sydney
```

On Unix like machines:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run(['cat', '/etc/timezone'], capture_output=True)
print(output.stdout.decode())
```

Output on my machine:

```
Europe/Berlin
```

Comment: 1. pytz is not the default component that is available when python 3 get installed in RedHat
2. The 'Australia/Sydney' is not manually supplied but obtained automatically from the system. same like timedatectl utility. Hope this helps

Comment: ZoneInfo doesn't retrieve the local zone. or at least I don't know how to use that to get local zone name. btw, i am testing it on RedHat but this script is required to run in Ubuntu and RedHat and in multiple zones.

Comment: On my xubuntu I can set it with the command `sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin`. It’s stored in cat /etc/timezone. In python `import os os.system(‘cat /etc/timezone’)`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But in RedHat this is different. Thats the reason i want to use python built-in functionality instead of calling the external command. timedatectl will serve the purpose if i want to use external command

Comment: The updated answer has 'Australia/Sydney' supplied. I want that information automatically obtained when running the script. This script may not be running only in 'Australia/Sydney' but also in some other region

Comment: @Ramanan, for Linux Xubuntu I added one possible solution above. But I think this request is very difficult as you can read in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). `timedatectl` should also available on [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-configuring_the_date_and_time).

Comment: Ther is also a [timezonefinder](https://pypi.org/project/timezonefinder/), but you said this isn't possible to use for you, unfortunatly.